# Function to represent the smallest element of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if there is a way to represent the smallest $x \in S$ where $S$ is some set of real numbers. According to the WOP, there must be a smallest value. But how do I go about representing the smallest value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Well ordering principle applies to sets of NATURAL numbers, not real numbers.   Examples of sets of real numbers without smallest numbers:  The set of all even integers (not bounded below).  The interval (0,1) (Has 0 as an infinum but no actual smallest element)

If you meant $S$ to be a subset of the natural numbers (Counting numbers), then the usual function we use is $\min S$ to indicate its minimum element, such as $\min \{1,2, 3\}=1$

(addendum: The LateX/Jax command is \min)

Comment: Is there a max then? Or since the WOP doesn't imply a largest value, there is no max?

Comment: Correct,   for instance,  the set of even counting numbers has no max.   If you have a set of natural numbers that is boundded above, there is a max, and you use \max for that